# Publishing a Simple Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I have created a game for Facebook using HTML, CSS and Javascript, which is nearly ready to be published.  The only features I have left are allowing the user to post their score to their wall and publishing both their and their friends' high scores.  Every tutorial or guide I've found for Facebook seems to be outdated and too unnecessarily complicated.  I'm completely lost as to what's the best approach to achieve my goals.  Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brent's answer was good, but what I ended up using was [TapJS](http://tapjs.com/pages/home).  TapJS is an online JavaScript game hosting platform which offers Facebook integration.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats, you've discovered how often Facebook has changed their API. I would suggest following the Javascript tutorial. It's probably the most straight forward, best user experience, and most future proof.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Essentially you are looking for 2 functions. FB.init and FB.ui.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It looks like the JS API is pretty good.  How do I handle the user data?  Do I need to write a server to store the user's scores or is something like that already available?

Comment: Yes, you would want to store the user data on your server. You can do that with Ajax calls.